# before.rules date

Tags: files, ufw, ls, timestamp

I can't figure out why one of my before rules file has a date that is in the future.

Today's date is July 3rd but the file time stamp states Jul 6.  Below is the output from `ls -l` in the `/etc/ufw directory` (bottom one).

Is this something that is supposed to be this way for a specific reason?  I don't know if something is screwed up.

My time and date settings are correct.  Thanks a bunch.

```
/etc/ufw$ ls -l
total 92
-rw-r----- 1 root root  913 Jun 19 13:56 after6.rules
-rw-r----- 1 root root  913 Apr  5  2012 after6.rules.20140331_213832
-rw-r----- 1 root root  913 Mar 31 21:42 after6.rules.20140331_214732
-rw-r----- 1 root root  913 Mar 31 21:48 after6.rules.20140427_143429
-rw-r----- 1 root root  913 Apr 27 14:35 after6.rules.20140430_185510
-rw-r----- 1 root root 1004 Jun 19 13:56 after.rules
-rw-r----- 1 root root 1004 Apr  5  2012 after.rules.20140331_213832
-rw-r----- 1 root root 1004 Mar 31 21:42 after.rules.20140331_214732
-rw-r----- 1 root root 1004 Mar 31 21:48 after.rules.20140427_143429
-rw-r----- 1 root root 1004 Apr 27 14:35 after.rules.20140430_185510
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 27 13:25 applications.d
-rw-r----- 1 root root 2718 Apr 30 18:55 before6.rules
-rw-r----- 1 root root 2718 Apr  5  2012 before6.rules.20140331_213832
-rw-r----- 1 root root 2718 Mar 31 21:38 before6.rules.20140331_214732
-rw-r----- 1 root root 2718 Mar 31 21:47 before6.rules.20140427_143429
-rw-r----- 1 root root 2718 Apr 27 14:34 before6.rules.20140430_185510
-rw-r----- 1 root root 2187 Jul  6  2014 before.rules
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never quite figured out what the deal was with this.  I re-installed the OS and setup my ufw rules like I did before.  I've been monitoring the before and after rules and the issue has not replicated.